# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'call') when trying to run crypto.createCipheriv

Tags: javascript, node.js, cryptojs

I keep getting this error when trying to create a cipher with CryptoJS. I am able to create the iv with no issue, but when I want to create the cipher itself it breaks

Here is my code:

```
const crypto = require("crypto");

const algorithm = "aes-256-ctr";
const secretKey = "blep";

const encrypt = (text) => {
  const iv = crypto.randomBytes(16);

// this is where it breaks giving the above mentioned error

  const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(algorithm, secretKey, iv); 

  const encrypted = Buffer.concat([cipher.update(text), cipher.final()]);

  return {
    iv: iv.toString("hex"),
    content: encrypted.toString("hex"),
  };
};

const decrypt = (hash) => {
  const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv(
    algorithm,
    secretKey,
    Buffer.from(hash.iv, "hex")
  );

  const decrpyted = Buffer.concat([
    decipher.update(Buffer.from(hash.content, "hex")),
    decipher.final(),
  ]);

  return decrpyted.toString();
};

module.exports = {
  encrypt,
  decrypt,
};
```

This is the full error code:

```
 index.js:7 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'call')
    at StreamCipher.CipherBase (index.js:7:1)
    at new StreamCipher (streamCipher.js:7:1)
    at Object.createCipheriv (encrypter.js:97:1)
    at Object.createCipheriv (browser.js:45:1)
    at encrypt (crypto.js:9:1)
    at ./src/services/service.js (service.js:5:1)
    at options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:24:1)
    at fn (hot module replacement:62:1)
    at ./src/pages/page.js (page.js:12:1)
```

Comment: What version of NodeJS do you have? I have `v18.12.1`, and this gives me a RangeError: Invalid key length; Setting `secretKey` to `crypto.randomBytes(32)` makes it work for me.

Comment: @AliNauman I am currently running Node V16.16.0, when I change it ```crypto.randomBytes(32)``` I get the following error: 

Uncaught TypeError: invalid iv length 32

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue the other day (Using ES6), I had:

```
import crypto from 'crypto'
```

And fixed it with two options:

1. Wildcard import: `import * as crypto from 'crypto'`
2. Dynamic import: `import { createDecipheriv... } from 'crypto'`

*To be honest with you I'm not sure why the normal import wasn't working.